# How do I set a setter for a subdocument in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[Subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) (embedded documents) in Mongoose can be specified in a schema like:

```js
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    children: [childSchema]
});
```

But how do I specify [setters](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set) on the collection and require that the array not be empty when the type is an embedded schema? This code will throw an errors that the embedded schema is not a valid type:

```js
function someSetter = function(val) {
    // Do something on set
    return val; 
};

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    children: [{type: childSchema, set: someSetter, required: true}]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set the setter after the Schema's instantiation.

```js
parentSchema.path('children').set(someSetter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
    children: [{type: {childSchema}, set: someSetter, required: true}]
});
```